# Calling an external function from within the oncreate function (Android)

Tags: java, android

This is my first time asking a question here, as most of the time I find the answer I need within these forums. However I've been searching for ages and have had no luck so thought I would just ask.

My issue is when I call an external function it throws an error "The method `processInput()`is undefined for the type new `TextWatcher(){}`" my code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.screenDisplay);
  myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    // Not used but required for method to work correctly
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    // Not used but required for method to work correctly
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    // Processing input as entered into screen
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        processInput();
    }
  });
}
```

and the external method I'm trying to call is processInput(){}. The code for the function wrapper is shown below:

```
public void ProcessInput(String input){}
```

Hopefully its not something silly like a missing bracket that I'm overlooking,

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
processInput();
```

instead try some thing like this. Make sure function name starts with small letter.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    ProcessInput(s.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, although now feel embarrassed, can't believe that I had just forgotten to pass the required input String. Correction worked like a charm, thanks again.

Comment: Its all fine mistakes happens :)

Comment: Thank you for the update, I noticed the issue with s not being a string after the function fix. Thank you for all your help.